# Get HttpServletRequest in JSR-303 Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a validation in my application that uses cookies (request.getCookies) to validate a captcha code.

I want to create a ConstraintValidator for this captcha validation, so it is validated alongside the other bean's attributes - as specified by JSR-303 Bean Validation.

Is there a way to retrieve the HttpServletRequest in a ConstraintValidator?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming (due to present tag) that you are having Spring, with the recent version of one (>=2.5.1), this should be as simple as

```
package org.yourapp.controller.validation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class YourValidator implements ConstraintValidator<YourValidatorAnnotaion, String> {
    // here should be autowired a proxy to currently undergoing request
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void initialize(YourValidatorAnnotaion constraintAnnotation) {
        // this should autowire all dependencies of this class using
        // current application context
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // here goes your custom logic for validation, like matching
        // captcha challenge to captcha response, but i am not doing
        // this for you, as i don't know what it supposed to be, so
        // i simply test presence of cookies.
        return request.getCookies().length > 0;
    }
}
```

For the completness, here is a sample `@YourValidatorAnnotaion` implementation:

```
package org.yourapp.controller.validation;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Constraint(validatedBy = YourValidator.class)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface YourValidatorAnnotaion {
    String message() default "No cookies - no validation";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Thats it. Now if you annotate your DTO field with `@YourValidatorAnnotaion`, you should get an error whenever controller with such `@Valid @RequestBody` argument will be called without cookies in request header.

Comment: Any chance you could supply a reference for this? I tested it, and it appears to work, but `ConstraintValidator` implementations must be thread-safe because they can be re-used. This doesn't appear that it could possibly be thread-safe. Thanks.

Comment: But it is thread-safe. HttpServletRequest being injected is just a proxy, which corresponds to current actual request and all request processing (including validation) in J2EE/Spring is done on thread-local basis, meaning each thread has distinct request for entirety of processing.

Comment: IntelliJ is showing me this error: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'HttpServletRequest' type found.` but the code works somehow. I checked in debug mode. Why is that?

Comment: @mantri 
IntelliJ apparently have not indexed spring context that registers that bean. Unless carefully configured, IntelliJ inspections regarding spring context are not particularly reliable, which can especially be the case with spring-boot and other runtime bean discovery mechanisms.